# How can I push a branch of my GitHub project repo to the Moovweb Cloud?

Tags: github, moovweb

I am using GitHub and have been pushing the master branch of my repo to the 
Moovweb Cloud. I have started branching my project.

How can I push a specific branch to the Moovweb Cloud?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your Git Remote setup look like? Use `git remote -v` to find out. What do your branches looks like? Use `git branch -r`.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you need to push the new branch to master. The Moovweb Cloud doesn't compile other branches. It's not meant to serve as a code hosting repository but rather to be used for testing and deployment.

So the code would be:

```
git push origin my_branch:master
```

This takes your "my_branch" branch and pushes it to master. You may need to add a "-f" to force push it over the last build.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your remote repository on Moovweb Cloud is 'origin' in your local repository :

```
git push origin my_new_local_branch
```

will push and create the new branch on your remote repository.

Comment: Like heroku, Moovweb Cloud ignores pushes on any branch besides master so this should be `git push origin your_local_branch:master` and you may very need to use `-f` to force the push. Beware that pushing a branch other than master could destroy your code on Moovweb Cloud which is ok if you have it saved on GitHub.